# Compile gedit 3 to use on Gnome 2

Tags: compiling, gnome, gedit, gnome2

I'm on Gnome 2.32.1 (Ubuntu 11.04), and I would like to use gedit 3 on my current desktop environment.

To achieve this, I think I could compile gedit 3 and its dependent libraries with a custom prefix, so it would not interfere with my current Gnome 2 libraries, but I'm not sure.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing this while I'm writing an answer, so I'm sorry if it's a bit messy in the end. I'm just assuming that the procedure will be the same for you.

### -- I'll get stuck myself a bit further on, so this isn't a full solution. It may help you to install intltool however, wich is a depency needed for gedit 3. Sorry and good luck.

1. Download the *gedit 3* package: http://ftp.acc.umu.se/pub/GNOME/sources/gedit/3.0/gedit-3.0.4.tar.bz2
2. Extract it and open a terminal in the folder where you extracted the archive.
3. Type *./configure*.
   This should be the output:

   robin@Robin-Latitude-D620 ~/Bureaublad/gedit-3.0.4 $ ./configure
   checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
   checking whether build environment is sane... yes
   checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
   checking for gawk... gawk
   checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
   checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
   checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
   checking for gcc... gcc
   checking whether the C compiler works... yes
   checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
   checking for suffix of executables... 
   checking whether we are cross compiling... no
   checking for suffix of object files... o
   checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
   checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
   checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
   checking for style of include used by make... GNU
   checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
   checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
   checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
   checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... 64
   checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
   checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
   checking for gcc... gcc
   checking whether we are using the GNU Objective C compiler... no
   checking whether gcc accepts -g... no
   checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
   checking for python... /usr/bin/python
   checking for python version... 2.6
   checking for python platform... linux2
   checking for python script directory... ${prefix}/lib/python2.6/dist-packages
   checking for python extension module directory... ${exec_prefix}/lib/python2.6/dist-packages
   checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
   checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
   checking how to print strings... printf
   checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
   checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
   checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
   checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
   checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
   checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
   checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
   checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
   checking whether ln -s works... yes
   checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
   checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
   checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
   checking how to convert i686-pc-linux-gnu file names to i686-pc-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
   checking how to convert i686-pc-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
   checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
   checking for objdump... objdump
   checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
   checking for dlltool... no
   checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
   checking for ar... ar
   checking for archiver @FILE support... @
   checking for strip... strip
   checking for ranlib... ranlib
   checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
   checking for sysroot... no
   checking for mt... mt
   checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
   checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
   checking for ANSI C header files... yes
   checking for sys/types.h... yes
   checking for sys/stat.h... yes
   checking for stdlib.h... yes
   checking for string.h... yes
   checking for memory.h... yes
   checking for strings.h... yes
   checking for inttypes.h... yes
   checking for stdint.h... yes
   checking for unistd.h... yes
   checking for dlfcn.h... yes
   checking for objdir... .libs
   checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
   checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
   checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
   checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
   checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
   checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
   checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
   checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
   checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
   checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
   checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
   checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
   checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
   checking whether to build static libraries... no
   checking for gtkdoc-check... no
   checking for gtkdoc-rebase... no
   checking for gtkdoc-mkpdf... no
   checking whether to build gtk-doc documentation... no
   checking for sigaction... yes
   checking for floor in -lm... yes
   checking for Win32 platform... no
   checking for native Win32... no
   checking for Mac OS X platform... no
   checking for native Mac OS X... no
   checking whether NLS is requested... yes
   checking for intltool >= 0.40.0... ./configure: line 13093: intltool-update: command not found
    found
   configure: error: Your intltool is too old.  You need intltool 0.40.0 or later.
4. We'll have to install intltool 0.40.0 or later first. Download link: http://launchpad.net/intltool/trunk/0.41.1/+download/intltool-0.41.1.tar.gz
5. Extract it somewhere and open a terminal inside the folder.
6. Run *./configure* here as well. Output:

   robin@Robin-Latitude-D620 ~/Bureaublad/intltool-0.41.1 $ ./configure
   checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
   checking whether build environment is sane... yes
   checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
   checking for gawk... gawk
   checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
   checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
   checking for perl >= 5.8.1... 5.10.1
   checking for XML::Parser... ok
   configure: creating ./config.status
   config.status: creating Makefile
   config.status: creating doc/Makefile
   config.status: creating intltoolize
   config.status: creating tests/Makefile
   config.status: creating tests/cases/Makefile
   config.status: creating tests/results/Makefile
   config.status: creating tests/selftest.pl
7. Run the *make* command. Output:

   robin@Robin-Latitude-D620 ~/Bureaublad/intltool-0.41.1 $ make
   Making all in tests
   make[1]: Map '/home/robin/Bureaublad/intltool-0.41.1/tests' wordt binnengegaan
   Making all in cases
   make[2]: Map '/home/robin/Bureaublad/intltool-0.41.1/tests/cases' wordt binnengegaan
   make[2]: Er hoeft niets gedaan te worden voor 'all'.
   make[2]: Map '/home/robin/Bureaublad/intltool-0.41.1/tests/cases' wordt verlaten
   Making all in results
   make[2]: Map '/home/robin/Bureaublad/intltool-0.41.1/tests/results' wordt binnengegaan
   make[2]: Er hoeft niets gedaan te worden voor 'all'.
   make[2]: Map '/home/robin/Bureaublad/intltool-0.41.1/tests/results' wordt verlaten
   make[2]: Map '/home/robin/Bureaublad/intltool-0.41.1/tests' wordt binnengegaan
   make[2]: Er hoeft niets gedaan te worden voor 'all-am'.
   make[2]: Map '/home/robin/Bureaublad/intltool-0.41.1/tests' wordt verlaten
   make[1]: Map '/home/robin/Bureaublad/intltool-0.41.1/tests' wordt verlaten
   Making all in doc
   make[1]: Map '/home/robin/Bureaublad/intltool-0.41.1/doc' wordt binnengegaan
   make[1]: Er hoeft niets gedaan te worden voor 'all'.
   make[1]: Map '/home/robin/Bureaublad/intltool-0.41.1/doc' wordt verlaten
   make[1]: Map '/home/robin/Bureaublad/intltool-0.41.1' wordt binnengegaan
   sed -e 's|[@]PACKAGE@|intltool|g' -e 's|[@]VERSION@|0.41.1|g' -e "s|[@]INTLTOOL_PERL@|/usr/bin/perl|g" -e "s|[@]INTLTOOL_LIBDIR@|/usr/local/lib|g" < intltool-extract.in > intltool-extract
   chmod +x intltool-extract
   sed -e 's|[@]PACKAGE@|intltool|g' -e 's|[@]VERSION@|0.41.1|g' -e "s|[@]INTLTOOL_PERL@|/usr/bin/perl|g" -e "s|[@]INTLTOOL_LIBDIR@|/usr/local/lib|g" < intltool-merge.in > intltool-merge
   chmod +x intltool-merge
   sed -e 's|[@]PACKAGE@|intltool|g' -e 's|[@]VERSION@|0.41.1|g' -e "s|[@]INTLTOOL_PERL@|/usr/bin/perl|g" -e "s|[@]INTLTOOL_LIBDIR@|/usr/local/lib|g" < intltool-update.in > intltool-update
   chmod +x intltool-update
   sed -e 's|[@]PACKAGE@|intltool|g' -e 's|[@]VERSION@|0.41.1|g' -e "s|[@]INTLTOOL_PERL@|/usr/bin/perl|g" -e "s|[@]INTLTOOL_LIBDIR@|/usr/local/lib|g" < intltool-prepare.in > intltool-prepare
   chmod +x intltool-prepare
   make[1]: Map '/home/robin/Bureaublad/intltool-0.41.1' wordt verlaten
8. Now, to make things a bit easier, install *checkinstall* and run `sudo checkinstall`. Just press enter on every question it asks and it should install intltool succesfully.
   Output:

   robin@Robin-Latitude-D620 ~/Bureaublad/intltool-0.41.1 $ sudo checkinstall

   checkinstall 1.6.2, Copyright 2009 Felipe Eduardo Sanchez Diaz Duran
              This software is released under the GNU GPL.

   The package documentation directory ./doc-pak does not exist. 
   Should I create a default set of package docs?  [y]:

   Preparing package documentation...OK

   Please write a description for the package.
   End your description with an empty line or EOF.

   > > 

   ---

   Debian package creation selected *

   ---

   This package will be built according to these values:

   0 -  Maintainer: [ root@Robin-Latitude-D620 ]
   1 -  Summary: [ Package created with checkinstall 1.6.2 ]
   2 -  Name:    [ intltool ]
   3 -  Version: [ 0.41.1 ]
   4 -  Release: [ 1 ]
   5 -  License: [ GPL ]
   6 -  Group:   [ checkinstall ]
   7 -  Architecture: [ i386 ]
   8 -  Source location: [ intltool-0.41.1 ]
   9 -  Alternate source location: [  ]
   10 - Requires: [  ]
   11 - Provides: [ intltool ]
   12 - Conflicts: [  ]
   13 - Replaces: [  ]

   Enter a number to change any of them or press ENTER to continue:

   Installing with make install...

   ========================= Installation results ===========================
   Making install in tests
   make[1]: Map '/home/robin/Bureaublad/intltool-0.41.1/tests' wordt binnengegaan
   Making install in cases
   make[2]: Map '/home/robin/Bureaublad/intltool-0.41.1/tests/cases' wordt binnengegaan
   make[3]: Map '/home/robin/Bureaublad/intltool-0.41.1/tests/cases' wordt binnengegaan
   make[3]: Er hoeft niets gedaan te worden voor 'install-exec-am'.
   make[3]: Er hoeft niets gedaan te worden voor 'install-data-am'.
   make[3]: Map '/home/robin/Bureaublad/intltool-0.41.1/tests/cases' wordt verlaten
   make[2]: Map '/home/robin/Bureaublad/intltool-0.41.1/tests/cases' wordt verlaten
   Making install in results
   make[2]: Map '/home/robin/Bureaublad/intltool-0.41.1/tests/results' wordt binnengegaan
   make[3]: Map '/home/robin/Bureaublad/intltool-0.41.1/tests/results' wordt binnengegaan
   make[3]: Er hoeft niets gedaan te worden voor 'install-exec-am'.
   make[3]: Er hoeft niets gedaan te worden voor 'install-data-am'.
   make[3]: Map '/home/robin/Bureaublad/intltool-0.41.1/tests/results' wordt verlaten
   make[2]: Map '/home/robin/Bureaublad/intltool-0.41.1/tests/results' wordt verlaten
   make[2]: Map '/home/robin/Bureaublad/intltool-0.41.1/tests' wordt binnengegaan
   make[3]: Map '/home/robin/Bureaublad/intltool-0.41.1/tests' wordt binnengegaan
   make[3]: Er hoeft niets gedaan te worden voor 'install-exec-am'.
   make[3]: Er hoeft niets gedaan te worden voor 'install-data-am'.
   make[3]: Map '/home/robin/Bureaublad/intltool-0.41.1/tests' wordt verlaten
   make[2]: Map '/home/robin/Bureaublad/intltool-0.41.1/tests' wordt verlaten
   make[1]: Map '/home/robin/Bureaublad/intltool-0.41.1/tests' wordt verlaten
   Making install in doc
   make[1]: Map '/home/robin/Bureaublad/intltool-0.41.1/doc' wordt binnengegaan
   make[2]: Map '/home/robin/Bureaublad/intltool-0.41.1/doc' wordt binnengegaan
   make[2]: Er hoeft niets gedaan te worden voor 'install-exec-am'.
   test -z "/usr/local/share/man/man8" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/share/man/man8"
    /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 intltoolize.8 intltool-extract.8 intltool-merge.8 intltool-prepare.8 intltool-update.8 '/usr/local/share/man/man8'
   make[2]: Map '/home/robin/Bureaublad/intltool-0.41.1/doc' wordt verlaten
   make[1]: Map '/home/robin/Bureaublad/intltool-0.41.1/doc' wordt verlaten
   make[1]: Map '/home/robin/Bureaublad/intltool-0.41.1' wordt binnengegaan
   make[2]: Map '/home/robin/Bureaublad/intltool-0.41.1' wordt binnengegaan
   test -z "/usr/local/bin" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/bin"
    /usr/bin/install -c intltool-extract intltool-merge intltool-update intltoolize intltool-prepare '/usr/local/bin'
   test -z "/usr/local/share/aclocal" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/share/aclocal"
    /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 intltool.m4 '/usr/local/share/aclocal'
   test -z "/usr/local/share/intltool" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/share/intltool"
    /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 Makefile.in.in '/usr/local/share/intltool'
   make[2]: Map '/home/robin/Bureaublad/intltool-0.41.1' wordt verlaten
   make[1]: Map '/home/robin/Bureaublad/intltool-0.41.1' wordt verlaten

   ======================== Installation successful ==========================

   Copying documentation directory...
   ./
   ./COPYING
   ./AUTHORS
   ./doc/
   ./doc/Makefile.am
   ./doc/intltoolize.8
   ./doc/Makefile.in
   ./doc/intltool-update.8
   ./doc/I18N-HOWTO
   ./doc/intltool-prepare.8
   ./doc/intltool-merge.8
   ./doc/intltool-extract.8
   ./doc/Makefile
   ./README
   ./TODO

   Copying files to the temporary directory...OK

   Stripping ELF binaries and libraries...OK

   Compressing man pages...OK

   Building file list...OK

   Building Debian package...OK

   Installing Debian package...OK

   Erasing temporary files...OK

   Deleting temp dir...OK

   ---

   Done. The new package has been installed and saved to

   /home/robin/Bureaublad/intltool-0.41.1/intltool_0.41.1-1_i386.deb

   You can remove it from your system anytime using:

   ```
     dpkg -r intltool
   ```

   ---

### 9. Back to the gedit terminal window. Run *./configure* again.

I'll just stop here, as it seems that I've gotten stuck a bit further on, and I don't want to risk my system's stability just to be able to use gedit 3. Sorry I couldn't be of more assistance. I'll leave this post as it is as it at least may help you with the intltool depecy problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help. If I succeed to install gedit 3, I'll complete steps.

Answer (score 0):

to compile gedit this is how i succeeded copy/pase this in the gnome-terminal
it will download the latest stable release of gedit and compile it

```
sudo apt-get build-dep gedit

cd /tmp
wget http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/gedit/3.2/gedit-3.2.6.tar.xz
tar Jxf gedit-3.2.6.tar.xz
cd gedit-3.2.6
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

**Source**:

- [How to compile and install gedit(-dash) in Ubuntu 11.10 - EuroBytes](http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/how-to-compile-and-install-gedit%28-dash%29-in-ubuntu-11.10)